# Purpose of thin bendable copper tubing under kitchen sink

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, kitchen-sink

The cold water line under my kitchen sink goes to a splitter (labeled "A" in the picture) with two ouputs and **my question is what is the purpose of the output labeled "C" which is a thin copper tube?**  Secondary question is why is this tube used instead of a rigid pipe or hose; this is the only such tube in my apartment.  Obviously appears bendable, but it's extremely stiff.  The valve handle for this output was almost fully tightened clockwise (which should be closed or almost closed).  There is no sound when it's opened or closed.

Not sure if it is relevant but the other output labeled B is a flexible hose running to my kitchen faucet.  The sink has a garbage disposal whose drain is the white pipe and electrical switch/power is the yellow wire.  Next to the sink is a dishwasher which is fed by a hose from the hot water line (not shown here).  There is a refrigerator about 10 feet away on the same wall, but it has no water dispenser nor ice maker.  On the other side of this wall is a bathroom shower.

[image: picture]

Comment: I’m going to guess that there was once a refrigerator with ice maker there. If you pull out the refrigerator, you may find the other end of the tube, hopefully capped.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't pull my fridge out by myself and I cannot see behind it, but sounds like a good theory.  Is this type of tubing specifically for such uses?

Comment: Common for older installations. Newer ones are usually plastic tubing, but otherwise similar. Could be various things (drinking water filter, etc.) but icemaker is a very common reason, especially with it going out of sight.

Comment: If you want to be able to move the fridge solo, you should be able to get teflon furniture slider pads at your local hardware store.  Use a prybar to lift the fridge and place the pads, then give the fridge the ol' slideroo.  Extremely heavy stuff can be moved on carpet or smooth floor with these.